# What does "Jimping" mean?

Tags: meaning, etymology

*Jimping* is a term used when describing knives, but I am unsure of what it really means.

See for example this [description of a keychain-sized tool](http://www.everydaycommentary.com/2011/11/gerber-shard-review_25.html) where *jimping* is mentioned, and even lauded for "working well".
According to Wikipedia, *Jimping* is supposed to be a sort of decoration (on the dull side) of a one-bladed dagger (specifically, a [Dirk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirk)).

Unfortunately, looking for a more precise explanation results, most of the time I am being asked if I just mistyped "jumping". :(

So what does it mean exactly? And what is the function?

Comment: On the page you posted: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-5vo578aQMK0/TmYAoxDdkoI/AAAAAAAAAK8/4zSxJ6Uo4iY/s330/5764843142_d869c96491_m.jpg

Comment: @mplungjan: Nice jimping! But there's still no way to tell what it is from the picture, unless you know what it is first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Googling provided me with the following information.

From [ebladestore](http://www.ebladestore.com/glossary.shtml):

> Lashing Grommets/**Jimping** - These terms refer to notches that are designed into the back lower part of the blade for better thumb control.

From [knifehog](http://www.knifehog.com/t-Guide_Knife_Glossary.aspx):

> **Jimping**: Notches down the spine of a blade created to provide grip on a knife beyond the bolster.

A post by Chris Meyer on [bladeforums](http://www.bladeforums.com/forums/showthread.php/690170-Jimping-by-machine-need-bit-advice) provides a definition along with some pictures:

> Jimps (or jimping) is what the groves on tang are called. They look good and help give you a better grip.
>
> [image: These are factory jimps on a new Dovo razor.] *These are factory jimps on a new Dovo razor.*

Answer (score 4):

Because the question has the tag, here's the etymology.

[Knife Anatomy, Parts, Names, Components, Definitions, and Terms](http://www.jayfisher.com/Knife_Anatomy_Parts_Names_Definitions.htm) says:

> **jimping**
>
> The old word, *jimp* that came from North England and Scotland, means neat, handsome, and slender in form. The knife industry designated regular, machined cuts or cross-hatched patterns on the back of the spine of the knife to improve traction of the fingertips *jimping*. They still call those regular spaced machine-made cuts jimping, but the in the custom and handmade knife world it has evolved into artistic filework. Jimping may be machine-cut by automated slitters, mills, or blades, but filework must be hand-cut. In my world, calling filework jimping is an insult.

The OED has the noun *jimp* as an obsolete Scottish meaning, from 1513:

> 1. A minute or subtle point; a trifling distinction; a quirk, subtlety; a tittle.

And from  1572:

> 2. A trick, prank.

They say it may be related to the Scottish and northern dialect adjective *jimp*, variously meaning slender, slim, delicate, graceful, neat or scanty; barely full; bare (measure).

> Known in Scots since c1500; origin obscure. It has been compared with gim *adj.*, ‘smart, spruce’, of the same age, and with jump *adj.*, exact, precise, which appears later; but in neither case is the sense congruous.

It's also used as *jimp-waisted*, such as this from 1826:

> That bonnie dark-haired..jimp-waisted lassie.